# Can't get user_context to pass into Sentry with Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, exception, middleware, sentry

My goal is to pass User Context like email or ID into Sentry so I can see which users broke something.

I've configured a piece of Global Middleware to add user context to my Sentry errors. Here is the class:

```
        class AddUserToSentry
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if(Auth::user())
        {
            //dd(Auth::user()->email);
            app('sentry')->user_context(array(
                'email' => Auth::user()->email
            ));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In my Handler.php I have:

```
 /**
 * Report or log an exception.
 *
 * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return void
 */
public function report(Exception $e)
{

    if ($this->shouldReport($e)) {
        app('sentry')->captureException($e);

    }
    parent::report($e);
}
```

What am I missing to make this work? All I get for user context is the IP address, which is not very helpful in my case.

Thank you very much,

Josh

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete example, the [source](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/php/integrations/laravel/#adding-context) is from the official Sentry documentation. To avoid having to add `use Auth;` you can simply use the `auth()` helper function.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SentryContext
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (app()->bound('sentry')) {
            /** @var \Raven_Client $sentry */
            $sentry = app('sentry');

            // Add user context
            if (auth()->check()) {
                $sentry->user_context(['id' => auth()->user()->id, 'email' => auth()->user()->email]);
            }

            // Add tags context
            // $sentry->tags_context(['foo' => 'bar']);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide access to Laravel's Auth Facade in your controller like so:

`Use Auth;`